# In which city is this building with the inscription "domus dei et porta coeli"?

Tags: identify-this, architecture, landmarks

Can anyone let me know where this was taken please?

[image: A tower with a clock next to a building with the inscription 'domus dei et porta coeli']

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You already have your answer, but for future reference, please add as much information as possible to [tag:identify-this] questions, to give as many clues as possible to users who may try to answer your question. Sometimes you have very little information to provide, but you always have at least *one* piece, and that is where you got the image from. This usually gives at least one good clue.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, that is Cittadella, province of Padua, Italy

https://traveling4numbers.com/tag/cittadella/

and aerial view [picture](https://i.redd.it/iqn0xerzuvzy.jpg):

[image]

another view [picture](http://www.italyheaven.co.uk/veneto/images/cittadella2.jpg)

[image]

it is really easy to spot since you can read clearly the

***domus dei et porta coeli***

meaning ***house of God and heavens door!*** in the main square church

Comment: @ΦXocę Did you take these photos yourself?  If not, do you mind adding a corresponding source?  Thanks!